# New Mobo, can't boot from usb

Tags: boot, usb, motherboard, power-supply

I just bought a new Motherboard because on my old computer it was making a lot of noise and sometimes the screen wouldn't turn on at boot. I assumed this was the mobo. * I have a feeling following the problems I'll explain that it may be a power supply problem..

So I bought a new mobo and installed a new windows install onto a usb using [this](https://www.microsoft.com/eb-gb/software-download/windows10). I've changed the BIOS startup config to use USB-FDD and USB-HDD on priority. The screen will go to the blue windows logo -on black background- and not do anything for over 20minutes.  Sometimes during this process the computer would even turn off and then on and start the process again. I haven't seen a progression from this screen.
Next I tried taking out the hdd and running the computer so just the usb is available to boot from. The computer will go to bios and not boot at all.

So it looks like my usb isn't being recognised... but it is! I have a usb with Tails iso. When I plug this in the computer will journey into that (with hdd in and out) but as soon as it starts loading up past the first screen it'll either turn off or freeze.

Also to prove the computer is recognising my usb is 'there' heres a screenshot of the loading screen which goes to the blue windows logo: (it shows at the top: USB STORAGE DEVICE: USB 3.0 FLASH DRIVE).

To prove my both my tails and windows usb's are working, I've run the windows usb on my laptop and it will run as expected (goes to windows setup through the usb).

I think the computer turning off at irregular times is quite odd. The fans also seem to stutter for a second,  a second after powering on.  Maybe this points to a PSU problem and the usb OS's wont load because the power supply is faulty? (but then they did on my old motherboard?-which had problems of its own[screen not working at startup sometimes])

Here's my system:
-old mobo: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A785M/
-new mobo: Gigabyte GA-78LMT-USB3 R2
-cpu: AMD Athlon(tm) 11 X4 630  2.8GHZ
-psu: http://www.ascendtech.us/macron-power-mpt-251-atx-power-supply_i_psmac250wmpt251.aspx (i'm pretty sure anyway)
-3 x ddr3 2gb ram
-gpu: https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/GTX750PHOC2GD5/

I think that's everything, please let me know if you'd like to see any photos of screens or more information.

[loading to os boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXL4b.jpg)

*******UPDATE*****
I followed instructions and got a new 500w power supply. I've also updated the BIOS. I've tried running both the tails and windows usb's. With the Tails one it restarts the computer while booting the OS and then goes to BIOS where it doesnt recognise any USB's are plugged in. With the Windows USB it freezes at the windows logo like before I got the new psu.

Any ideas?  Here are some ideas I'm having but would like input on them:

-cpu has gone bad. It doesnt explain the problems i was having before i swapped the motherboard for a new one but it does explain the OS's freezing/turning off right when they start to boot?

Comment: A 250W old&crappy power supply is probably not enough for a new mobo and a GTX750 graphics card.

Comment: Make sure you plug in the USB stick in a USB 2.0 port (black), not a USB 3.0 (blue/red).

Answer (score 0):

I would go for both suggestions in comments. You definitely need at least 500W PSU, or one that is specified on your cards box as minimum.

And use USB2.0 ports for booting, also put Legacy boot mode support in BIOS, that should help.